# How can we randomize a mapping/function?

Tags: probability, functions

Suppose we have a set $A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose also that we have a injective function $f:A\to[0,1]$ which maps each element of $A$ to a real number between $0$ and $1$.

I want to write an explicit formula of $f$ that randomly assigns elements of $A$ to the closed interval$[0,1]$ But my issue is that I am not sure how to randomize the function $f$.

Is it possible to define an explicit formula of $f$ which randomizes the mapping of the elements of $A$ to $[0,1]$? My guess is that because of the closed interval $[0,1]$, function $f$ is common in mathematics, though I couldn't find anything.

I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: Do you mean *injective functions*? Since there is no bijection from a finite set to $[0,1]$. Also, what kind of randomness do you want? Even for coin tossing, where you have only two possible outcomes, you have freedom to choose the probability at which the head appears. Then in this case, you have infinitely many possible outcomes...

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes, my bad! I edited my question to correct the mistake! Thanks.
I am not sure how to describe the "randomness." But as a "designer", say, it doesn't make a lot of sense to explicitly define the formula of function $f$, right?

Comment: @SangchulLee For example, if $f$ is a social preference weight function then ideally we'd want to randomize the mapping of the elements of $A$ to the interval $[0,1]$. The output will give you a scale of preference then.

Comment: What I wanted to say was that there are enormously many different ways to create a random function $f : A \to [0,1]$, hence the word 'randomize' is not so well-defined. One simple choice is to assign each $f(a_i)$ a value uniformly chosen from $[0, 1]$, independently of all the others. But this means that any profile is equally likely, which is very unlikely if you want to model a real situation. In full generality, you may regard $f=(f(a_1),\cdots,f(a_n))$ as random vector, and in order to generate a random vector, you need to specify the joint distribution.